# Get the type of a property of an Union Type in typescript

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have some interfaces with a `name` property (and possibly others):

```js
interface Circle {
   name: 'circle',
   radius: number
}

interface Sphere {
   name: 'sphere',
   radius: number
}

interface Square {
   name: 'square',
   side: number
}

type GeometricalObject = Circle | Sphere | Square;
```

Now, suppose we have a function:

```js
   doSomething(name: SomeType) {
     ...     
   }
```

Is there a way to assure that the `name` argument's type of `doSomething()` function is the union of the `name` property possible types in GeometricalObject (i.e. 'circle' | 'sphere' | 'square', in this specific case) programmatically?

I was imagining something like `typeof GeometricalObject.name`, if that was possible.

Comment: You mean `type Shape =  GeometricalObject["name"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface Circle {
   name: 'circle',
   radius: number
}

interface Sphere {
   name: 'sphere',
   radius: number
}

interface Square {
   name: 'square',
   side: number
}

type GeometricalObject = Circle | Sphere | Square;

type Name = GeometricalObject["name"]; // "circle" | "sphere" | "square"
```

It is possible; it's using bracket notation instead of dot notation.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gWAChkSQ4BbCALmQHIENsJaAaIk5KOAE2AFcAzjRB9yAI2hEAvkSKhIsRCgDKABwAW0PO1IVqdARq2sdnHvyHIR4yYRmE54aPCTJlARz5wo24rso0tAKe3sxsfsgCwNz61hJQ0rKEYACeqigA4hAA9pRgUMAIcFgA8mIAVhAIYMgAvGiMOMgAPm5GPi1uIT4A3Emp6cgAcnp1yFm5EPmFxWWV1QDaAERklEsAuj1AA)

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
interface Circle {
    name: 'circle',
    radius: number
}

interface Sphere {
    name: 'sphere',
    radius: number
}

interface Square {
    name: 'square',
    side: number
}

type GeometricalObject = Circle | Sphere | Square;

type GeometricalObjectType = Circle['name'] | Sphere['name'] | Square['name'];
function doSomething(name: GeometricalObjectType) {
    switch(name) {
        case 'circle':
        break;
        case 'sphere':
        break;
        case 'square':
        break;
    }
}
```

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/AQ4SwOwFwUwJwGYEMDGNgGExxQG3QN4BQopwESAtjAFzADkK2eM9ANCWSHEgCZgBXAM50IAygCN4nEAF8iM8NHjI0wAMoAHABbxCi0hWp16QnXvYHQPfsNHipcRfMWRYiVOnUBHAUjj6XCBGtAxCvv6sHEHAQmC8oWKS0qQupFAAnproAOIwAPbUUHBgKEi4APISAFYwKFDAALyYzPjAAD4a5gEdGhEBANwK6Vm5BUUlZZU1dVAAKqNNLTj4ANr0IfQAur1augHrmzudPn4HG1SsW0OkCAIQ9WD5EMC8+eqFMFDakADmABQhOh5T7FUrlKq1eoLbIASmAxBiQgA7mAoChtIDLvDETFQGUhOhGK1WDQrFwJAEkABrG54kAEolmfak8lkSkwGl0+mMsL9Vn0kAcrls+SpIhAA